# IS HTML5 Support IOS 8.2

Tags: ios, iphone, html

I have created one html 5 page in my ios apps. In that page I used camera click activity to click image and send to my server. But after click on browse button it shows menu click image or browse image from camera folder. After click on any of these buttons my web view gets closed.

My code is working in ios6 fine but its not working in ios 8.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>

    <title>Take or select photo(s) and upload</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function fileSelected() {

            var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

            document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "";

            for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {

                var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];

                var fileSize = 0;

                if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)

                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';

                else

                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

                document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += 'Name: ' + file.name + '<br>Size: ' + fileSize + '<br>Type: ' + file.type;

                document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += '<p>';

            }

        }

        function uploadFile() {

            // ...
            var myParam = getParameterByName("User_id");

            var fd = new FormData();

            var count = 1;//document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

            var exptext = document.getElementById('myText').value;

            var category = document.getElementById('ddlcategory');

            var selectedCategory = category.options[category.selectedIndex].text;

            for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {

                //var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
                var file = "ios.png";
                fd.append(file.name, file);

            }


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

            xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

            xhr.open("POST", "savtofil.aspx?User_id= " + myParam + "&Category=" + selectedCategory + "&Exptext=" + exptext + "&Imgname=" + "ios.png");//+ file.name);

            xhr.send(fd);

        }

        function uploadProgress(evt) {

            if (evt.lengthComputable) {

                var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);

                document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';

            }

            else {

                document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';

            }

        }

        function uploadComplete(evt) {

            /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */

            alert("Successfully Uploaded!");


        }

        function uploadFailed(evt) {

            alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");

        }

        function uploadCanceled(evt) {

            alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");

        }

        function getQueryString() {
            var result = {}, queryString = location.search.slice(1),
                re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

            while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
                result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
            }

            return result;
        }



    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #myText
        {
            width: 239px;
            height: 43px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Upload.aspx" >

    <div>

    <p>
          <label for="fileToUpload">Take or select photo(s)</label> </p>
    <p>

     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" />         </p>

    <p>      
        <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" style="width: 142px" />
    </p>

    </div>

    <div id="progress"></div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```